# Statically linking curl using openssl in Windows

Tags: c++, curl, gcc, openssl

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Mingw64 with gcc 7.2.0
- Msys2 64bit (with latest upgrades using pacman) for compiling open source libraries
- Codeblocks for my
  program, using mingw64 and its gcc for my toolchain

I've been trying to link libcurl statically with ssl and ssh2 but having bunch of undefined reference found.

My Mingw64 is installed on C:/mingw64 and the Windows path is including C:/mingw64/bin

I compile openssl using Msys2 with these options:
./config no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5
make depend && make && make install
I then copy the libssl.a and libcrypto.a over to C:/mingw64/opt/lib
and the appropriate include files to C:/mingw64/opt/include

I compile and install ssh2 similarly, using these options
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-examples-build
make && make install
and then copy the libssh2.a over to C:/mingw64/opt/lib

I compile and install curl, using these options
./configure --enable-crypto-auth --with-ssl --with-libssh2 --disable-shared --enable-static
make && make install
then copy the libcurl.a over to C:/mingw64/opt/lib

in my program I define these:
CURL_STATICLIB
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
and link these libraries in order:
libcurl.a
libssh2.a
libws2_32.a
libssl.a
libcrypto.a
libwldap32.a
..other libraries that my program need

a few of the errors at linking are those:

- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-setopt.o):setopt.c undefined
  reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-url.o):url.c undefined
  reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-mprintf.o):mprintf.c
  undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-formdata.o):formdata.c
  undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libssl.a(t1_enc.o):t1_enc.c more undefined
  references to `__imp___acrt_iob_func' follow
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c undefined
  reference to `__imp_shutdown'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(bss_conn.o):bss_conn.c undefined
  reference to `__imp_htonl'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c undefined reference
  to `__imp_gethostbyname'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c undefined reference
  to `__imp_htonl'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(pem_lib.o):pem_lib.c
  undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c undefined
  reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
- C:\MingW64\opt\lib\libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c undefined reference
  to `__imp_CertFreeCertificateContext'

I'm guessing it has to do with openssl and/or the fact that I want curl static, since when I compile curl without ssl and linking my program with curl statically, it works, and if I compile the program linking to libcurl.dll.a and with curl having ssl it also works (but needs the curl dll at run time). I want curl to use ssl, and having the whole program linked statically. How can I fix my issue? Maybe the Mingw64 and Msys2 are not using the exact same toolchain, how can I verify this and fix it if that's the case?

Comment: If you move libws2_32.a somewhere after libcrypto.a, and add libcrypt32.a, most of them should be fixed. But I don't know about those missing acrt_iob_func, never had that one.

Comment: your suggestions helped. My lib order is now:
libcurl.a
libssh2.a
libssl.a
libcrypto.a
libcryp32.a
libws2_32.a
libwldap32.a
..other libraries that my program need

Now my undefined reference are down to 7, and all related to acrt_iob_func

Comment: Could it be that my mingw64 is using gcc 7.2.0 and msys2 is using 7.3.0?

Comment: Are you saying that you use 2 different gcc versions?

Comment: Well I'm under windows, and so I have Mingw64 installed, and for the "unix" like interface I have Msys2 (which is the tool I use to compile the libraries). And they both have their own gcc executable separately. The Msys2 can update itself with pacman -Syuu to the latest gcc available from the repository, but Mingw64 does not have a tool to update itself, and you have to grab the latest installer, which I guess does not contain the latest gcc. I'm not sure it is an issue however.

Comment: Looks like the acrt_iob_func stuff was only [very recently](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/af149abc81550de19a80fba0f9d0e89fe4d01f2f/) introduced. And I guess your gcc version has a mingw-w64 that's more recent than that. That's why I haven't seen this before, mine is a bit older. Oh, and this seems to have been [noticed before](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/3237).

Comment: Would you know of a work around? (rolling back to a previous gcc version, or perhaps manually updating the mingw64 but I wouldn't know how to do that)

Comment: Did you try [Downgrading packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/downgrading_packages)?